# Jetpack Compose KeyboardType for DateTime?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I managed to create a `TextField` for a date using [`KeyboardType.Number`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/KeyboardType). Now I would like to create a `TextField` for a time but there is no KeyboardType with ":" like the [`TextInputType.datetime`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html) in Flutter. Is there another way to accomplish this in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Aleksey Sinelnikov I figured out a way:

```kotlin
class TimeTransformation: VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val trimmed = if (text.text.length >= 4) text.text.substring(0..3) else text.text
        var output = ""

        for (i in trimmed.indices) {
            output += trimmed[i]
            if (i < 3 && i % 2 == 1) output += ":"
        }

        val timeTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
            override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                // [offset [0 - 1] remain the same]
                if (offset <= 1) return offset
                // [2 - 3] transformed to [3 - 4] respectively
                if (offset <= 3) return offset + 1
                return 5
            }

            override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                if (offset <= 1) return offset
                if (offset <= 4) return offset - 1
                return 4
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(output), timeTranslator)
    }
}
```